# AngularJS adding incremental numbers to a select list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I want a select box where I can choose from a list with a min/max number.

Currently my number is just 1 to 10  so I have the below.

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
            <select ng-model="selectedItem"
                ng-options="opt as opt for opt in options">
            </select>
            The value selected is {{ selectedItem }}.
    </div>
</body>
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.options[1];
});
```

What is the best approach here?  For example if I wanted to choose from numbers between 1 and 100 I wouldn't want to list each number just the lowest and highest.
With vanilla JS I was thinking something like the below but looking for a more angular approach here so I can easily use ng-model to update my data.

```
var selectList = '<select>';
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
      selectList += "<option value="+ x +">" + x + "</option>";
}
selectList += '</select>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [];

  //Fill array with incremental numbers
  while ($scope.options.length < 100){
    $scope.options.push($scope.options.length + 1);
  }

  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.options[1];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to turn it into a filter, especially if you're going to be reusing it:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"
 ng-options="opt as opt for opt in [] | minmax:1:10">
</select>

angular.module("demoApp").filter("minmax", function() {
  return function(arr, min, max) {    
    min = parseInt(min);
    max = parseInt(max);
    for(var i=min; i <= max; i++){
       arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
  };
});
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for further reading on how filters work.

Comment: ooh I like it, nice and dry and easily re-usable throughout the project! Since he is relatively new you may also want to add in a link to the angular js documentation on filters for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use lodash or underscore _.range(100); i recommend lodash,

also you can write your own function something like this and add it to utilities js that you use across the project

```
    var range = function (n) {
    var numbers = [];
    if (n < 0) return numbers;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    numbers.push(i + 1);
    return numbers
}
```

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple examples that immediately come to my mind using a for loop and a while loop.

For loop example:

```
var x = 0;
var max = 100;

$scope.options = [];

for (x = 0; x < max; x++) {
    $scope.options.push(x);
}

$scope.selectedItem = $scope.options[1];
```

The second way with the while loop would look something like this:

```
var x = 0;
var max = 100;

$scope.options = [];

for (x = 0; x < max; x++) {
    $scope.options.push(x);
}

while (x < max) {
    $scope.options.push(x);
    x++;
}

$scope.selectedItem = $scope.options[1];
```

The big thing here is that you declare your array first with nothing in the square brackets to initialize, then you can utilize javascripts .push() to append an element onto the end of the array through each iteration of whichever style loop you prefer.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Hope that helps!